# I want to uniquely identify each coulmn value in a SQL select statement without displaying the actual data using some sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

For example:
I have a table `BILL_PRODUCT`

```
product_vendor_id| product_site_id| type_of_product |
123              | 901            | Car
123              | 901            | Tyre
123              | 902            | Bike
124              | 801            | skateboard
123              | 901            | Car
.
.
.
```

The product `vendor_id` and `product_site_id`  have one- many relation.

I want to to write a  select statement something like

```
select product_vendor_id,product_vendor_site_id,type_of_product, count(1)
from PRODUCT where product_type is not hull
group by product_vendor_id,product_vendor_site_id,type_of_product
order by product_vendor_id,product_vendor_site_id;
```

to get the count here. But in my select statement I do not want my `product_vendor_id` and `product_site_id` to be visible directly. I want data to be in this format

```
product_vendor_id| product_site_id| type_of_product |count 
  1                    1               car              2
  1                    1               tyre             3
  1                    2               bike             5
  2                    1               skateboard       1
  .                     
  .
```

Could you help me to write the SELECT  query.

Comment: I hope you meant `product_type is not null` and not `product_type is not hull`

Comment: By the way, it won't affect the results but `count(*)` is the standard expression in SQL, not `count(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses `dense_rank()` to generate new ids:

```
select 
    dense_rank() over(order by product_vendor_id) new_product_vendor_id,
    dense_rank() over(order by product_site_id) new_product_site_id, 
    product_type,
    count(*) 
from product 
where product_type is not hull 
group by product_vendor_id, product_site_id, product_type
```